# How to calculate the total working hour if login time is more then one in the table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter. I am calculating the total working hours in a day.

So what I am doing is, When user login in the system It will insert the login time in the table and `is_active` status will `1`. Something like this

[image]

If the user log out then it will update the logout time and `is_active` status will `0`.

[image]

If the same user login again then it will insert the new login time
[image]

Same process for logout.
I can calculate the time between two dates but in my scenario, the user can log in multiple times.

I am displaying the list of the record which is `is_active` status is 1.

**Model**

```
public function get_current_login(){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_employee');
        $this->db->join('tbl_current_login','tbl_current_login.emp_id=tbl_employee.id');
        //$this->db->where($where);
        $this->db->where('is_active',1);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result(); 
          if($result)
          {
            return $result;
          }
          else 
          {
            return 0;
          }
    }
```

Above code will display the list of the user where `is_active` status is 1.(I haven't shared the view and controller code).

Now I have to calculate the total working hours in a day.
Is I am on the right path to insert and update the login and logout time? 
Is it possible to calculate using MYSQL or I have to use PHP?

Comment: You could just use the logout_time as it is always 0000-00-00 00:00:00 when isactive = 1 and greater than 0000-00-00 when isactive =0. These two columns essentially code for the same info and the risk when that happens is things going out of sync and confusing reports/software...

Comment: @CaiusJard, Thanks for the reply, So what is the best way to handle this? because at the end of the month I have to get the report and display the first time login in the system on each day. I am not updating the login_time when user is still in th system.

Comment: At the end of the month you want a report of each day and the hours worked that day?

Comment: @CaiusJard, Yes at the end you the day I have to calculate the working hours, also I am displaying the current total hours. I mean user login around 10 am and still in the system and I checked again around 2 pm so total hours 4 hours till now

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports TIMESTAMPDIFF:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

You can use it to give the number of hours or fractional hours between two datetimes

If you want a reasonably precise number of hours out of it, you can ask for the number of seconds between two times and divide the result by 3600

If you’re doing reports that calculate how many hours an employee worked per week or per month, group by employee and week/month and sum the hours. To reduce a date to a week or month granularity use the YEAR() function and the MONTH() or WEEK() functions

Example:

```
SELECT emp_id, year(login_time), month(login_time), sum(timestampdiff(second, login_time, logout_time)/3600.0)
FROM timeclock
WHERE logout_time > ‘0000-00-00’
GROUP BY 
  employee_id, year(login_time), month(login_time)
```

Substitute week in for month if you want the report weekly

Heres a report that gives the login and logout time on each date and the hours worked that day:

```
SELECT emp_id, year(login_time), month(login_time), day(login_time), min(login_time), max(logout_time), sum(timestampdiff(second, login_time, logout_time)/3600.0)
FROM timeclock
WHERE logout_time > ‘0000-00-00’
GROUP BY 
  employee_id, year(login_time), month(login_time), day(login_time)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I read DATEDIFF before posting the question but my issue is, I have multiple times login time. DATEDIFF  will calculate with two dates. right?

Comment: For example: first time login 2018-09-20 09:05:42 and logout 2018-09-20 09:07:17 so the total time is 0:1:35. now user again login 2018-09-20 09:09:10 and not log out because of user still in the system.

Comment: You have multiple times on different rows, you’re only really interested in the total of all rows, hence the group by and sum

Answer (score 0):

I usually calculate the time after fetching data from database.

```
<?php

// Let's assume the $result is the database records result

$current_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$total_duration = 0;
foreach ($result as $row)
{
    // Set logout date as current date if user still logged in
    if ($row['logout_time'] === '0000-00-00 00:00:00') $row['logout_time'] = $current_date;
    // You may need to group the total duration based on employee id
    $total_duration += strtotime($row['logout_time']) - strtotime($row['login_time']);
}
```

Comment: I am getting output -1537414750

Comment: How do I display like a time?

Comment: Wow, you’d drag a million rows across a network just to add them up in the client, something the database can do far more easily and quickly, with less network traffic?

Comment: I believe you won't get million of rows for login data of employees in a day

Comment: @user9437856 you would get minus if the logout_time is '0000-00-00 00:00:00', you need to fix that first to be the end of the day (e.g '2018-09-18 23:59:59').
You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6534559/2284740) for formatting the duration

Comment: @sofyan, logout time is 0000-00-00 00:00:00 because the user is still in the system

Comment: I know, I already updated my answer, you can see I set the logout time to current date to prevent the wrong calculation you get before

Comment: @sofyan How do you know this isn't for a government/massive corporate/facebook 2? You don't.. But that's not really the point I'm making; I'm calling you out on your general assertion that whenever you have to do some reporting, you drag all the data out of the database and count it in the front end code. That's a poor solution on all kinds of levels

Answer (score 0):

You will get the time in second and can convert in your format.

```
select sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,login_time,logout_time)) from table_name group by date(login_time),id;
```